# How to get the files count in a variable of particular directory in GitHub actions YAML file?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

How to get the files count in a variable of particular directory in GitHub actions YAML file ?

I need to get the exact files count in a directory and store the value in a variable. I have using the Github actions YAML file with a windows machine. So, need to get the result in this process.

Could you suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filenames don't have newlines, you can do this, where `$DIR` is your directory:

```
$ find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | wc -l
13
```

If you want to store it in an environment variable, you could do this:

```
COUNT=$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | wc -l)
```

Note that you will need to use `bash` for this if you're on Windows.